# How to define UI in Xamarin with code

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, event-handling, xamarin.android

XAML page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="Phoneword.MainPage">
         <ContentPage.Padding>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                        iOS="20, 40, 20, 20"
                        Android="20, 20, 20, 20"
                        WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
         </ContentPage.Padding>
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         Orientation="Vertical"
                         Spacing="15">
                <Label Text="Enter a Phoneword:" />
                <Entry x:Name="phoneNumberText" Text="1-855-XAMARIN" />
                <Button x:Name="translateButon" Text="Translate" Clicked="OnTranslate" />
                <Button x:Name="callButton" Text="Call" IsEnabled="false" Clicked="OnCall" />
                <Button x:Name="callHistoryButton" Text="Call History" IsEnabled="false"
              Clicked="OnCallHistory" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

Methods:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Phoneword
{
    public class Mainpage : ContentPage
    {
        static string translatedNumber;

        public Mainpage()
        {
            Button CallHistoryButton = new Button() { Text = "Call History", IsEnabled = false };
            CallHistoryButton.Clicked += OnCallHistory;

            Button CallButton = new Button() { Text = "Call", IsEnabled = false };
            CallButton.Clicked += OnCall;

            Button TranslateButon = new Button() { Text = "Translate" };
            TranslateButon.Clicked += OnTranslate;

            Entry PhoneNumberText = new Entry() { Text = "1-855-XAMARIN" };
        }

        /// <summary><para>
        /// Will be executed in response to the Translate button and will translate entered string to number.
        /// </para></summary>
        void OnTranslate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            translatedNumber = Core.PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(TranslateButton.Text);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(translatedNumber))
            {    
                CallButton.IsEnabled = true;
                CallButton.Text = "Call " + translatedNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                CallButton.IsEnabled = false;
                CallButton.Text = "Call";
            }
        }

        /// <summary><para>
        /// Will be executed in response to the Call button.
        /// Will try to dial the entered string, if succeed will add it to the phonebook.
        /// </para></summary>
        async void OnCall(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (await this.DisplayAlert(
                    "Dial a Number",
                    "Would you like to call " + translatedNumber + "?",
                    "Yes",
                    "No"))
            {
                var dialer = DependencyService.Get<IDialer>();
                if (dialer != null)
                {
                    App.PhoneNumbers.Add(translatedNumber);
                    CallHistoryButton.IsEnabled = true;
                    dialer.Dial(translatedNumber);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary><para>
        /// Will be executed in response to the CallHristory button.Will add the number to the CallHistory
        /// </para></summary>
        async void OnCallHistory(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new CallHistoryPage());
        }
    }
}
```

When i'm trying to do it with XAML it works.It doesn't care that the buttons aren't defined, because they're in the XAML page.
I think i should add new class with only constructor with these controls and then i must inherit it, so i will have an access to them.
It's basically https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/ the first parts from Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Forms.Multiscreen ,but i'm trying to do it with UI code,Events,Async.

Comment: Well, you create buttons, so far so good, but at some point you've got to put them into the page... The `ContentPage.Content` and the `StackLayout` you have in the XAML aren't there just for show ;)

Comment: I'm new in Xamarin,what i've got to do?Should i do Content class?

Comment: Create a new `StackLayout`, put your buttons inside of it, then assign the `StackLayout` to the `Content` property of your page

Comment: var stackLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Spacing = 10,                             
            };
            stackLayout.Children.Add(CallHistoryButton);
            stackLayout.Children.Add(CallButton);
            stackLayout.Children.Add(TranslateButton);
            stackLayout.Children.Add(PhoneNumberText);
            Content = stackLayout;
Thank you,but i have another problem.
translatedNumber = Core.PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(Content.FindByName<Button>("TranslateButton").Text);
I cant find the Button that i seach for,please help me again :)